# Initialize dynamically allocated structures within dynamically allocated structures

Tags: c, struct, calloc

I want to dynamically allocate structures within structures. I think I can do this. However when I want to perform operations with them, I get an access violation error under Visual C++. Perhaps there is something wrong with the initialization. By the way, how can I initialize `myDynamicMembersBinArray` being dynamically allocated? I tried the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main()
{
    /* ========== Define structures ========== */

    /* Create just the identifier */
    struct bin{
        char *tag;
        float size;
    };
    /* Declare another structure which will hold the bin structure */
    struct dynamicbin{
    struct bin *binPointer;
    };
    /* I use calloc so that zero-filling is done */
    myDynamicMembersBinArray = (struct dynamicbin*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct dynamicbin));
    struct bin *binpointer = (struct bin*)calloc(N, sizeof(struct bin));

    /* This one fails */
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%f\n", (*(*myDynamicMembersBinArray).binPointer+i).size);
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do not cast the results of `malloc()` & al. Actually do not cast void * to any other pointer type. Also, ` malloc()` & co might return NULL. **Always** check for this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Firstly, I just wanted to make the allocation work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not declare `myDynamicMembersBinArray`:
`struct dynamicbin* myDynamicMembersBinArray = calloc(1, sizeof(struct dynamicbin));`

`struct bin *binpointer = (struct bin*)calloc(N, sizeof(struct bin));` should be
`(*myDynamicMembersBinArray).binPointer = calloc(N, sizeof(struct bin));`
(the parentheses around `*myDynamicMembersBinArray` are important) or better
`myDynamicMembersBinArray->binPointer = calloc(N, sizeof(struct bin));`

and last but not least
`printf("%f\n", (*(*myDynamicMembersBinArray).binPointer+i).size);` should be
`printf("%f\n", *((*myDynamicMembersBinArray).binPointer+i).size);`
(note the * moved outside the of the parentheses) or much better
`printf("%f\n", myDynamicMembersBinArray->binPointer[i].size);`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I created myDynamicMembersBinArray, but forgot to paste it into the code here.
After I have corrected the other two things, error messages occur, namely:

in case of "myDynamicMembersBinArray->binpointer = calloc(N, sizeof(struct bin));" a value of type void* cannot be assigned to an entity of type bin.
in case of "printf("%f\n", *((*myDynamicMembersBinArray).binPointer+i).size);" expression must have class type.

As I mentioned, I use Visual C++.

Comment: I realized that the first issue was about the C++ development environment. I ran it on tcc, and it became OK. But for the printf section tcc said: lvalue expected.

Comment: It works if I write: printf("%f\n", (*(*myDynamicMembersBinArray).binPointer).size);

Comment: `printf("%f\n", (*(*myDynamicMembersBinArray).binPointer).size);` will always print the one with the index 0, not with the index `i`. this will work: https://ideone.com/x9VrtD

Comment: My last question is: what is the case when `myDynamicMembersBinArray` is allocated to be of size `M`, i.e.:
`const int M = 4;
 struct dynamicbin* myDynamicMembersBinArray = calloc(M, sizeof(struct dynamicbin));`

In this case 
`for (int j=0; j<M; j++) 
   for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
     printf("%f\n", myDynamicMembersBinArray->binPointer[i].size);
  }`
won't work. Somehow, I have to step the pointer `myDynamicMembersBinArray`.

Comment: I tried:
`printf("%f\n", myDynamicMembersBinArray[j]->binPointer[i].size);`, but it does not work.

Comment: you should use `printf("%f\n", myDynamicMembersBinArray[j].binPointer[i].size);` to get the `j`'th element of `myDynamicMembersBinArray`.

Comment: All right. So the idea behind your solution is the following: first, allocate the outer structure and then all the elements of the inner structure array. Thank you again, it was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
struct bin *binpointer = (struct bin*)calloc(N, sizeof(struct bin));
```

Should be:

```
(*myDynamicMembersBinArray).binpointer = calloc(N, sizeof(struct bin));
```

Note I got rid of the cast.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858) for why (keeping in mind that in C++, you do need the cast.  But it is wrong in C and can hide errors).

Comment: `*myDynamicMembersBinArray` needs to be in parentheses to work correct and casting the return value of `malloc` is not wrong in C, it is only not good to do this.